# Issue with instance variables

Tags: java, instance, method-call

My overall goal at the moment is to call a method that is in a different class, there is no inheritance between the classes.

After researching i found the best way to do this was to initialise an instance of the object in the method I am trying to call it in. 
Is there a standard way to do this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet right now would be to read a tutorial, or the course book. You seem to be struggling with some basic concepts here, that _must_ be understood before starting to code.

Answer (score 1):

> i get the error "Constructor Book in class Book cannot be applied to
>   given types

Because you did'nt specified a [no-args constructo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)r in your `Book` class

---

I assume that you want to check if the book already exists

won't compile since this method (i.e the method `checkForDuplicate()`) doesn't return a boolean in all the cases (when b.equals() is false).

So you should do

```
if(b.equals() == true){
  return true;
}else {
  return false;
}
```

which is equivalent to `return b.equals();`

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the correct parameter *values*, not declare them again. Like this:

```
Book b = new Book(title, author, publisher, year);
```

Of course, you have to know the values for title, author, publisher, year before calling the constructor. Also, the method is expecting a `boolean` return value, so you must have a `return true;` or `return false;` at the end, depending on what the method is expected to do.

Comment: @user2904018 after you've correctly called the constructor, you can call methods of the class `Book` on the object `b`, for instance: `b.getTitle()`. But first (and there's no escaping this!) you have to pass the right parameters to the constructor.

Comment: Looks like checkForDuplicate() needs some parameters too, like title, author, publisher, year.

Comment: @user2904018 of course, because you have not defined it yet - it's in my answer: **you have to know the values**. Or simply pass the values directly: `new Book("The Hobbit", "J.R.R. Tolkien", "George Allen & Unwin", 1937)`.

Comment: @user2904018 I'm sorry, but you have to take a look at a tutorial first, before starting to code.